# Adobe PDF forms submit opening outlook new email windows in Safe mode

Tags: vba, outlook, pdf-form

We have PDF forms. Business user fills data in the form and click on submit button which opens a new email window of Outlook with predefined email IDs and the form data attached as XFDF. Later user clicks on a button in outlook ribbon which calls the macros to sign, encrypt, send and then archive the message. It had worked successfully for 3 years.

The outlook ribbon button stopped calling Macro in November-2019. The ribbon button works perfectly if we open Outlook new email window directly from Outlook but was not working when opened from Adobe PDF forms. After alot of investigation, we have found that the Outlook new email window has been opening in Safe mode when Adobe PDF form invokes it, so the Outlook macros are not callable (new email window opens in safe mode even though outlook is in normal mode).

The forms use below code to submit PDF form data as XFDF to Outlook:

**this.submitForm({cURL: cEmailURL, bAnnotations: true, aFields: aSubmitFields,cSubmitAs:"XFDF", cCharSet:"utf-8"}**

Please help us to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the Trust Center settings in Outlook. Most probably somebody has changed the Macro Security to `Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled` on the `Developer` tab in Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, I have checked it. It is present as **Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)**. I am doubting it can be because of some update to outlook as it stopped working in all machines on same day.